# How to add responsive COLLAPSABLE table in email with CSS?

Tags: php, html, css, email, responsive

I tried this, and worked in normal browser (Chrome):

HTML with CSS:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.table td,
.table th {
  padding: 12px 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.table th {
  background-color: darkblue;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.table tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}


/*responsive*/

@media(max-width: 500px) {
  .table thead {
    display: none;
  }
  * {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .table tr {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
  .table td {
    text-align: right;
    padding-left: 50%;
    text-align: right;
    position: relative;
  }
  .table td::before {
    content: attr(data-label);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    padding-left: 15px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" charset="UTF-8" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <table class="table">

    <thead>
      <th>S.No</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Marks%</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td data-label="S.No">1</td>
        <td data-label="Name">Dinesh</td>
        <td data-label="Age">34</td>
        <td data-label="Marks%">50%</td>
        <td data-label="Staus">Passed</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td data-label="S.No">2</td>
        <td data-label="Name">Kamal</td>
        <td data-label="Age">23</td>
        <td data-label="Marks%">70%</td>
        <td data-label="Staus">Passed</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td data-label="S.No">3</td>
        <td data-label="Name">Neha</td>
        <td data-label="Age">20</td>
        <td data-label="Marks%">90%</td>
        <td data-label="Staus">Passed</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td data-label="S.No">4</td>
        <td data-label="Name">Priya</td>
        <td data-label="Age">30</td>
        <td data-label="Marks%">30%</td>
        <td data-label="Staus">Failed</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

The code is from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZtopjfXhUZI).
If I would like to send the table in email, the content which needs to be on left side isnt there.

Here is a picture:

[image]

I think content before CSS doesn't work.

I tried to send it with `php mail()` function to google account.

Comment: If the lack of support for generated content is what makes this fail, then you could try a reverse approach. Have the “generated” content be _actual_ content instead, have the necessary cell labels directly in the cells to begin with - wrapped into a span or something, so that they can be _hidden_ in desktop view then.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal, in the mail the properties `position` and `content` are not supported. https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/reference/supported_css

Comment: Hello there, I see you're a new user. When you answer a question please follow [this guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), they say that you shouldn't just say he can't do something, you should also provide an alternative to achieve the desired result. When you don't know how to do it you can comment instead.